# How to build portableapps project

Tags: delphi, build-process

I want to build this project on windows from source code.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/

I have downloaded the source code. But I have no idea how to build it.

EDIT---------
Actually I downloaded the source codes. But, I don't know using which software I have to open/build the source. 
For example, for .NET projects, I would use Visual Studio. I need to know which IDE is required for this project

Comment: Where did you manage to *find* the Delphi source code? All I can find are the installer and the launcher, which are not in Delphi.

Comment: @Rob, if you click on the 'Files' link in the header bar, it takes you to a list of different installers; a few of them also contain links marked (source). Maybe that's what the OP is referring to, although the question doesn't mention it.

Comment: @Sarwar Erfan, *which* source codes? The IDE you need to build each one depends on the language/platform it's for, and you didn't specify which version your question is about... If you're asking for a single IDE for *all* source code on that page, you won't find one.

Comment: I downloaded this:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/Source%20%28PortableApps.com%20Plat%29/PortableApps.com%20Platform%202.0%20Beta%205%20Source/

ANd, I want to build on Windows.

Comment: @Sarwar Erfan, OK. We're halfway there. :) Now what platform (Windows, Linux, etc.) do you want to build it for? (What OS will you want to run the Launcher on?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the launcher, then the source can be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/Source%20%28PortableApps.com%20Plat%29/).  I was able to build 2.0 beta 5 from source.  I got an error running it, but didn't investigate further.

I have to say, the source code for this project is pretty well hidden.  A comment in [this blog post](http://portableapps.com/blogs/johnhaller/2011-03-04_status_update) suggests that the latest version requires Delphi XE.  If you are using an earlier version, this could be the problem.  Otherwise, you'll need to be more specific about what's going wrong.

Comment: +1 Nice find, Bruce. @Rob and I must have both missed platform source link.

Comment: I mean the launcher. What Software (IDE) is required to open up the project and build?

Comment: @Sarwar,  As I mentioned in my answer, I believe you need Delphi XE.

Comment: @Bruce mentions Delphi XE http://www.embarcadero.com/delphi, which is the name of the IDE.

Comment: @Bruce: Seems Delphi XE is a pretty costly tool. Downloading trial version.... Any low cost/free alternative?

Comment: @Sarwar, They have recently released a less expensive "Starter" edition.  I haven't tried building the launcher with it, so I'm not sure if it is missing anything that you would need.  Details on the product web page.  http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi

Comment: The closest thing to a free alternative is the [Lazarus](https://www.lazarus-ide.org) IDE and [FreePascal](https://www.freepascal.org) compiler, however the PortableApps.com Platform sources are not tested with these and likely can't be compiled using these tools without a *non-trivial* amount of effort.

Comment: @3D1T0R: The [Delphi Starter Edition](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/starter/free-download) is now available for free.

Comment: Perhaps I should have said "free", as Lazarus ans FreePascal are Open Source. It's good to know that Delphi Starter Edition is free now, however you do apparently have to give them your phone number and agree to receiving "Embarcadero marketing communications via email and phone call".

Comment: You need an EDN account. I don't think you need to agree to receive emails or give out your phone number in order to get one.

Comment: @BruceMcGee: Sorry, I didn't get notified of your reply.

Comment: Visiting the link you posted, it says "All fields are mandatory", and it wouldn't let me download it without giving a phone number.

Comment: You're right. I only saw the EDN login because II already have an EDN account.